# problema con URL amigables y variables de sesion

Tags: apache

Tengo una web que maneja una variable de sesión en todas los modulos, este me sirve para reconocer al usuario que este "logeado" tengo que cambiar las url's normales a amigables, y me e ayudado del RewriteRule.
por el momento logre generar la url amigable con todo y la sesion hecha
quedando de este modo :

```
http://mi-sitio.com/inicio/jlllURL3Hf/
```

Donde "jlllURL3Hf" es extraido de la DB como la sesion ya "logueada"
ok, mientras la sesion exista y la variable este siendo recogida por las paginas no hay problema alguno
el problema se precenta, en el momento en que necesito ver la pagina sin la sesion hecha, como cualquier usuario que entra por primera vez, al no tener la variable hecha por la sesion, simplemente la url amigable no funciona arrojando un **`error 404`**.

esta es la manera en que tengo el `.httaccess` hasta le momento.

```
 RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 


RewriteRule acerca/(.*)/(.*) empresa.php?scid=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule contact/(.*)/(.*) contacto.php?scid=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule inicio/(.*)/(.*) index.php?scid=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule tienda/(.*)/(.*) productos.php?scid=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule novedades/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) productos.php?scid=$1&id=$2&new=$3
RewriteRule promos/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) productos.php?scid=$1&id=$2&promo=$3
RewriteRule catalogo/(.*)/(.*) descripcion_producto.php?scid=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule preguntas_frecuentes/(.*)/(.*) faqs.php?scid=$1&id=$2
```

obiamente hay algo mas que devo agregar al codigo del `htaccess`, mas no doy en el clavo.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule acerca/(.*)/(.*)/$ empresa.php?scid=$1&id=$2

Te falta "/$" entre la regla.

Comment: Hola...pues intente  colocar lo que faltaba, y no aun asi no funciona, ahora con o sin la variable de sesion hecha arroja un 404, ya revise que el archivo de destino exista

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando esta regla:

```
    RewriteRule ^p/(\w+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1 [L]
```

a mi me funciona muy bien.

Comment: ehmm bueno sigo con el problema inicial... si la url se escribe 
mi-sitio.com/inicio/jlllURL3Hf la pagina va sin problema, el problema sucede cuando ya no hay mas variable  despues de  inicio

http://imeldajoyas.com/inicio/jlllURL3Hf  esta la url que me funciona
con esta regla :
RewriteRule ^inicio/(\w+)/?$ index.php?scid=$1 [L]
si le quitamos lo que le sigue a inicio, se hara un error 404

Comment: Entonces deberías implementar una regla la cual no reciba variables.
RewriteRule inicio/(.*)/(.*) index.php [L]

Comment: Pues.. no amigo, 404... si la direccion recive la variable de sesion
/jlllURL3Hf
ahora deve existir esa variable, si no.. Pum! 404...

Comment: creo que esta opcion es correcta en el php debes validar si la sesion esta activa y alli hacer el redirect

Comment: esque en si la sesion si esta activa, puesto que la valido y de ser true, en el menu aparece el nombre del usuario... de lo contrario abre la posibilidad de loguearse... ademas lo se cuando en el redirect manda el 404, pues si no existe es obvio que no hay variable y genera el error.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que recibí de su parte, la solucion a mi problema fue lo siguiente :
hice 2 reglas separadas para cada caso en el sitio, ejemplo

```
Rewriterule ^inicio$ /index.php
```

En esta linea especifico que la URL "inicio" solo deberá hacer referencia al index.php en caso de no existir variable de sesión hecha. de modo que tendremos :
misitio.com/inicio

```
RewriteRule ^inicio/(.*)/(.*) index.php?scid=$1&id=$2
```

Aquí estoy especificando que encaso de existir la variable de sesión, hecha por el usuario la URL  /inicio/ABC123/ 
aplicara para la anterior URL index.php?scid=ABC123
de este modo logre hacer que la url quedara "amigable" para ambos casos.